# String substitution shell for latex

Tags: regex, shell, sed, latex, quotes

I'm trying to adapt an article to include it in a LaTeX Document. For that I'm using sed to substitute characters. However I find myself with a problem with some symbols like quotation marks. So for example with this paragraph:

> Los problemas de Europa no son los mismos en todos los países. "Alemania no está creciendo rápidamente, pero consiguió evitar la recaída en la recesión", dice Guillen. "En Irlanda, por ejemplo, la economía cayó un 20%. En Francia, la situación no es desesperada, pero el país tampoco es ninguna Alemania". Mientras, Italia y España han vuelto a caer en la recesión, y Reino Unido acaba de anunciar que está nuevamente en recesión.

The " symbol (double quote in a single character) should be changed to a `` if it's found at the beginning of a word but to a '' (they are 2 characters: \x27\x27) if it's at the end. So the resulting paragraph should be (the % sysmbol was also changed):

> Los problemas de Europa no son los mismos en todos los países. ``Alemania no está creciendo rápidamente, pero consiguió evitar la recaída en la recesión'', dice Guillen. ``En Irlanda, por ejemplo, la economía cayó un 20\%. En Francia, la situación no es desesperada, pero el país tampoco es ninguna Alemania''. Mientras, Italia y España han vuelto a caer en la recesión, y Reino Unido acaba de anunciar que está nuevamente en recesión.

I imagine that a regexp combining a space symbol and word to match at beginning should work, and a similar one for the end, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check that the `"` is either at the beginning of a line or preceded by a whitespace:

```
sed -r 's/(^| )"/\1``/g' filename
```

If your version of `sed` doesn't support extended regular expressions, you could say:

```
sed 's/\(^\| \)"/\1``/g'` filename
```

For escaping `%` and possibly other characters like `&`, `$`, you could make use of a character class to escape all those in one go:

```
sed -r 's/([$%])/\\\1/g' filename
```

The two could be combined too:

```
sed -r 's/(^| )"/\1``/g; s/([$%])/\\\1/g' filename
```

EDIT: From your clarification, it seems that you need to say:

```
sed -r 's/(^| )"/\1``/g;s/"/'"''"'\1/g' filename
```

Comment: if posix sed, due to missing group `()`, you could use a 2 substituion instead `'s/^"/``/;s/ "/ ``/g'` and use a temporary file becasue `-r` is missing in this case

Comment: @NeronLeVelu If `-r` is missing, I'd prefer `sed 's/\(^\| \)"/\1``/g'` instead.

Comment: but if r is missing, grouping is certainly also missing like on my AIX or SUN

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Sorry, I'm not much educated.  Feel free to post an answer that you think works.

Comment: There's a problem with your command: it't not the same " that '+' (I wrote the + because on the website they substitute the double character to its single equivalent, so the visual difference it's not appreciated). The first it's just one character, the second are 2 characters. That means that the " (in one character) found in the original text at the end of a word should be replaced by the '' (2 characters).

Comment: @Álvaro So it seems that the `"` in the pattern in the mentioned command needs to be replaced with `''`.

Comment: Not exactly, your command works perfectly for the " substitutions at the beginning of a word. The problems is that it does not match the endings. So for example: "aa bb cc" before aa the substitution is correct, but after cc it does nothing. In both cases a " have to be substituted, but depending on whether is found at the beginning or end of the word the new characters are different (`` vs '+')

Comment: @Álvaro It would be nice if you could edit the question instead and ensure that the characters appear properly in there -- whether those are double quotes, backticks, or a combination of single quotes.

Comment: Unfortunately this webpage substituted the 2 single quotes into one double quote. But to better clarify the answer, knowing that \x27 - single \x22 - double --> "aa bb cc" should be ``aa bb cc\x27\x27

Comment: I found an alternative way that solves the problem: sed -r 's/(^| )"/\1``/g; s/\>"/\x27\x27/g; s/(^| )\x27/\1`/g; s/([&$%])/\\\1/g' this also substitutes one character I didn't consider: ' at the beginning of a word single ' to a single `. However there's still one issue: when a paragraph ends in something like ?" the substitution is not done

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should change the "  to ``  if its in a beginning of a word.

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^"/) sub(/"/,"``",$i)}1' file
Los problemas de Europa no son los mismos en todos los países. ``Alemania no está creciendo rápidamente, pero consiguió evitar la recaída en la recesión", dice Guillen. ``En Irlanda, por ejemplo, la economía cayó un 20%. En Francia, la situación no es desesperada, pero el país tampoco es ninguna Alemania". Mientras, Italia y España han vuelto a caer en la recesión, y Reino Unido acaba de anunciar que está nuevamente en recesión.
```

It test one by one by one word and see if its starting with `"`, if yes change it.

Answer (score 0):

For posix

```
sed "s/^\"/``/;s/ \"/ ``/g;s/\"$/''/;s/\" /''/g" YourFile > TempFile
mv TempFile YourFile
```

for gnu sed version (not testing machine here to validate)

```
sed -r "s/\( |^\)\"/\1``/g;s/"\( |$)/''\1/g" YourFile
```